# Center div with text inside

Tags: javascript, css, center

I have a div element with following css and I need to center this inside parent container:

```
 <div id='download_confirm'>DOWNLOAD STARTED</div>

.download_confirm{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    padding:10px;

    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#fff;

    background:#ccc;

}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: If you want it positioned relative to its parent, then why is its positioning "absolute"?

Comment: @user2736012 "position:absolute :-
position it at a specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor or to the containing block. Absolutely positioned boxes can have margins, they do not collapse with any other margins." so nothing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, give `position:relative` to you div's parent element.

**1) -  if you want this div to be centered horizontally and vertically, then:**

```
.download_confirm{
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height: 90px;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    padding:10px;

    margin-top: -45px;
    margin-left: -100px;

    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#fff;

    background:#ccc;
}
```

.

**2) - if you want your div to be centered only horizontally, then:**

```
.download_confirm{
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height: 90px;

    padding:10px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#fff;

    background:#ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is no width or height,then this will be the solution,

This will position the `div` with `position:absolute` in `relative` with the parent `div`,

```
.download_confirm{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;

    padding:10px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#ccc;
}
<div class="download_confirm">DOWNLOAD STARTED</div>
```

and [check this:Absolute Horizontal And Vertical Centering In CSS](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/) very useful.

> You just need this, it's that simple, no need to know widths, heights,
>   nothing:

Answer (score 0):

if you only want horizontail center then give your div a width and set left and right margins to auto. Lose the posistion, top and left css lines.

but if you want vertical and horizontal center i suggest javascript to get viewport size and then set left and top positions. Easier solution is to use bootstrap or some other frameworks alert plugin.

See:
http://getbootstrap.com/index.html
or
http://jqueryui.com/

.download_confirm{

```
width: 100px;
margin: 0px auto;
padding:10px;

font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
color:#fff;

background:#ccc;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use # to select an id instead of a period which denotes a class selection, then set width and margin-left and margin-right set to auto